# warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettimeofday’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Tags: c, include, time.h

I have a `lib.h` file, inside which I use the function `gettimeofday`:

```
struct timeval tn;
struct tm *time;
gettimeofday(&tn, NULL);
time = gmtime(&tn.tv_sec);
```

I included the library `time.h`:

```
#include <time.h>
```

And the function works perfectly, I can correctly print the time of the day. Then why is this warning happening?

```
In file included from main.c:1:
lib.h: In function ‘execute_remote_script’:
lib.h:86:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gettimeofday’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   86 |     gettimeofday(&tn, NULL);
```

In `main.c`:

```
#include "lib.h"
```

Comment: According to [the official POSIX `gettimeofday` reference](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/gettimeofday.html), the correct header file to include is `sys/time.h`. It also states that the function is obsolete and that [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html) should be used instead.

Comment: Please  don't put executable statements in header files.

Comment: Try having another file (*lib.c*) that includes *lib.h*, and then link the 2 objects together :)

Answer (score 1):

add #include <sys/time.h>

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.